# Computing lim sup and lim inf of $\exp(n\sin(\frac{n\pi}{2}))+\exp(\frac{1}{n}\cos(\frac{n\pi}{2}))$ and $\cosh(n\sin(\frac{n²+1}{n}\frac{\pi}{2}))$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, limsup-and-liminf

It's the first time I encounter lim sup and lim inf and I only just know about their definitions. I have difficulties finding out about lim sup and lim inf of the following sequences
$$\exp\left(n\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)\right) + \exp\left(\frac{1}{n}\cos\left(\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)\right)$$
and 
$$\cosh\left(n\sin\left(\frac{n^2+1}{n}\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right).$$

For the first one, I have the strong intuition that lim sup is infinite and maybe lim inf is 1? For the second one I'm really lost... Can you help me? Tell me how you proceed?

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Welcome to our site!

Comment: For the first one it may be worth considering the subsequences $x_{4n+1}$ for limsup and $x_{4n}$for liminf can you see why? Also for the second one it will probably help to note $cosh(x)=\frac{1}{2}(e^x+e^{-x})$

Comment: For the first one, the subsequence $x_{4n+1}$ is $\exp((4n+1))+1$ and the subsequence $x_{4n}$ is $1+\exp(\frac{1}{4n})$ so I take the limit as $n$ tends to infinity of these and get infinity for the first one (the lim sup is infinite) and 2 for the second (but that only tell me the lim inf is smaller than 2 doesn't it?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note**: After submitting the answer I realized that I've made a mistake. The conclusions that I draw are to be referred to $\sup$ and $\inf$ of the sequences, and not $\limsup$ and $\liminf$. I apologize for the error. I wanted to delete the answer, but then reconsidered it and I'll leave it here in case someone will find it useful. The reader should read those $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ as $\sup$ and $\inf$.

Let
$$a_n = \exp\left(n\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)\right) + \exp\left(\frac{1}{n}\cos\left(\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)\right)$$

We have that
$$\begin{align}
n = 2k &\implies \sin\left(n\frac\pi2\right) = 0\text{ and }\cos\left(n\frac\pi2\right) \in \{-1, 1\} \implies a_{2k} = 1 + \exp\left(\frac1n(-1)^k\right)\\
n = 2k + 1 &\implies \cos\left(n\frac\pi2\right) = 0\text{ and }\sin\left(n\frac\pi2\right) \in \{-1, 1\} \implies a_{2k+1} = \exp\left(n(-1)^k\right) + 1
\end{align}$$

We see that, as $k \to +\infty$, $a_{2k} \to 2$ and this subsequence attains its minimum and maximum values respectively when $k = 1$ and $k = 2$ (because it's oscillating around $2$ and the limit is $2$). So
$$\left\{a_{2k}\right\} \subseteq \left[1+\exp\left(-\frac12\right), 1 + \exp\left(\frac14\right)\right]$$
For the second one, we see that $n(-1)^k$ is divergent: as $k \to +\infty$, when $k$ is even $a_{2k+1} \to +\infty$, while when $k$ is odd we have that $a_{2k+1} \to -\infty$. Hence
$$\left\{a_{2k+1}\right\} \subseteq \left(1, +\infty\right)$$

Hence, we conclude that
$$\liminf a_n = 1,\qquad\limsup a_n = +\infty$$

---

For the second exercise, observe that $\cosh x \in [1, +\infty)$ and the minimum value is attained when $x = 0$. Also note that $\cosh x$ is an even function. We will now study the inner function to determine its behavior. Let
$$b_n = n\sin\left(\frac{n^2+1}n\frac\pi2\right)$$
As $n \to +\infty$ we can consider three subsequences of $b_n$:
$$\begin{align}
b_{n_k} &\to +\infty\\
b_{m_k} &\equiv 0\\
b_{l_k} &\to -\infty
\end{align}$$

We are not interested in finding $n_k$, $m_k$ and $l_k$, but it is fairly easy to prove that they exist. Hint: recall that $n \to +\infty$ and use the fact that $\sin x \in [-1, 1]$.

Putting it together:
$$\cosh\left(b_{n_k}\right) = \cosh\left(b_{l_k}\right) \to +\infty$$
$$\cosh\left(b_{m_k}\right) \equiv 1$$

Therefore, denoting the whole sequence with $a_n$, we have:
$$\liminf a_n = 1,\qquad\limsup a_n = +\infty$$
where $1$ is also a minimum.

Comment: At the beginning, you wrote $a_{2k+1}$ tends to $-\infty$ when k is odd, you meant 1, right?

Comment: @Noome: Yes, I meant $1$. But I'm just going to delete the answer, since it's not correct. What I wrote applies for $\sup$ and $\inf$, not for $\limsup$ and $\liminf$.

Comment: Right, I think I get it :) Thank you very much, it's a insight that I'll be able to use applied to other similar problems, it'll be very usefull!

Comment: Your infinite answers are definitely right...